# Magento attribute type issue

Tags: magento, attributes

I'm using Magento EE 1.14.2. I'm trying to export all attributes with its type in web service. All is working fine but `weight` attribute. Its a system attribute. The attribute type should be  `text` but it's showing me `weight`. I checked fresh magento also. My code is,

```
$attribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'weight');
print_r($attribute);
```

My o/p is like,

```
 [attribute_id] => 80
            [entity_type_id] => 4
            [attribute_code] => weight
            [attribute_model] => 
            [backend_model] => 
            [backend_type] => decimal
            [backend_table] => 
            [frontend_model] =>
```

> [frontend_input] => weight

```
            [frontend_label] => Weight
            [frontend_class] => 
            [source_model] =>
```

Any hints or Ideas ,
Thanks.

Comment: If you'll check the attribute in the DB you'll find out it's actually `decimal` not `text`
SELECT * FROM `eav_attribute` WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'weight'

Comment: yeah, but I can see the type is text in admin.

Comment: What you're seeing in admin is the frontend input. The `weight` input type is actually a text input. `class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Weight extends Varien_Data_Form_Element_Text`

Comment: I want to get it's input type. It's type is 'text'. So how can I get it for decimal type ?  Any idea ..?

Comment: Assuming them you have a custom module/script for exporting attributes you should create a special case for the weight attribute when you export it just like Magento team did when rendering the frontend input